# How to achieve infinite scrolling with asp repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, infinite-scroll

My web project uses LINQ To SQL to access the data and a repeater control to display it.
To my knowledge, the repeater doesn't have a paging system built into it like a GridView does, so I thought I'd opt for an infinite scroll.

I found [this jquery plugin](http://jscroll.com/) that seemed to work initially although after a few tests, I found that it wasn't "hiding" items anymore.

The project uses a "behind-the-scenes" class where the data access is done, clearing up the page's partial class to handle how the data is displayed:

```
// App_Code/netGuestData.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using netguestModel;

public class netguestData
{
    private netguestEntities ne = new netguestEntities();

    public netguestData()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public IEnumerable<post> GetPosts()
    {
        var posts = from p in ne.posts
                     select p;

        return posts;
    }
}

// ~/Default.aspx.cs
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            loadGuestbook();
        }
    }

    private void loadGuestbook()
    {
        netguestData nd = new netguestData();

        rptGuestbook.DataSource = nd.GetPosts();
        rptGuestbook.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here's the markup...

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptGuestbook" OnItemCommand="rptGuestbook_ItemCommand"
    OnItemDataBound="rptGuestbook_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div runat="server" id="divPost" class="post">
            <div runat="server" id="divAuthor" class="author">
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlAdmin" CssClass="delete-button" Visible="false">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDeletePost" CssClass="button" Text="Delete Post"
                        CommandName="DeletePost" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("postid") %>' />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblShowEmail" Text='<%# Eval("showemail") %>' CssClass="hidden"></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Posted By: </span>
                        <%# Eval("postauthor") %><br />
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkWeb" ImageUrl="~/Images/webicon.png" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("webaddress") %>'></asp:HyperLink></li>
                    <li>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkEmail" ImageUrl="~/Images/emailicon.png" NavigateUrl='mailto: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "emailaddress" %>'></asp:HyperLink></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div runat="server" id="divMessage" class="post-message">
                <div class="post-date"><span>Posted On:</span> <%# Eval("postdate") %></div>
                <%# Eval("postmessage") %></div>
                <div class="scroll"></div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

It's all pretty straightforward. To achieve infinite scroll with the repeater, I found [this article on dotnetcurry](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=345) but this just does everything in the _Default partial class which doesn't suit me at all.

I've been trying to figure out how to tweak this example to fit my situation, but so far, I'm coming up empty.

If anyone can help me to make infinite scrolling work on my project - even if you just explain the concept of what I have to do - I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I asked in a group on facebook and someone there suggested lazy loading.

[Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057563/lazy-loading-repeater-has-linq-query-not-yielding-results#20057742) I asked a little while ago that has all the details.

**NOTE:**
After changing my code to take the answer to the question into account, I've noticed that this doesn't add the 2nd/3rd/4th/etc set of 10 rows to the existing set as I had expected.